# How to return very inserted ID from table with SequelizeJS?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table that has an identity ID. This value is auto incremented whenever a new record is inserted to the given table. However, I'm not able to return the very inserted ID in response to my query.

```
module.exports = sequelize.define('MyTable', {
    aField1: Sequelize.STRING,
    aField2: Sequelize.STRING,
    id: { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true }
})
```

The item is properly inserted to the database by calling `create()` function, but no ID is returned with the executed query. The log says me the following:

```
Executing (fdfd7f79d028c57c1c6f): 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] ([aField1], [aField2]) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES ('aValue1', 'aValue2');
```

How can I return the inserted ID in this Sequelize query?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand you only want to send ***id*** as response.
The code should look like

```
`.post((req, res, next) => {
    DATABASE_NAME.create(req.body)
    .then((result) => {
        //console.log(result);
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(result.id);
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
})`
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not quite like this. The result does not contain the inserted id into the response, only the fields I've mentioned above. That's why I'm struggling to get the inserted ID. Is there any option that I need to send through?

Comment: Make sure your code is right. var Sequelize = require('sequelize'); var sqlUrl = require('../config').sqlUrl; var db = new Sequelize(sqlUrl); var DBNAME = db.define('MyTable', {........ and so on

Comment: The code is right, I just cutted the bits that doesn't matter to the post.

Comment: Can you try with capital 'id' field instead of lower. That is 'Id' instead of 'id'.